# What scenario might require the use \ need of const pointer to (non-const\const) data

Tags: c++, pointers, constants, const-pointer

I understand the concept of `final` in Java or `const` in C++ for forcing constant values and allowing the compiler to enforce that on anyone using the modules you write.

I am not able to see where would you want to have a `const` pointer, why would you not want the pointer to change regardless of the data being constant or not:

e.g

why this?

```
char greetings[] = "Hello";

char * const p = greetings;  // const pointer, non-const data

const char * const p = greetings; // const pointer and const data
```

I cannot visualize an exmaple where you want to keep the pointer const, could it be for a file handle or something similar? or just a pointer to an object you don't want to change?

Comment: One example I can remember is head of link list, you don't want called function to change head, when you just want it to traverse.

Comment: `std::vector<int *>::push_back`'d better take its argument by const reference - i.e., by reference to const pointer to int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to make a pointer itself constant for several reasons:

- **Helping others understand your code** - When you declare a pointer and make it constant, you tell the readers that there are no changes done to that pointer in the rest of your function, so they would have a better idea of how you use the pointer.
- **Helping others maintain your code** - Someone else who maintains your code after you will have better idea of what you expected to do with the pointer. If he tries to pass a non-constant reference or a pointer to the pointer that you declared `const`, the compiler is going to catch this error.
- **Enable compiler optimizations** - When compilers see something declared `const`, they can optimize more aggressively.